# How to get Account Id 2 levels up in Trigger?

Tags: trigger

We have a scenario of accounts who have contacts where some have one or more records in a custom object named members__c but not all contacts have a member__c record. member__c object has a lookup relationship with the contact object.

I need to do a SOQL query and the WHERE clause need the accountid.

I try the following code to get the id and it returns null. What to do?

```
   trigger trgr_Update_BOG_Members_List on BOG_Membership__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

        ID currID;
        for(BOG_Membership__c a: Trigger.new){
            currID = a.Contact__r.AccountId;
         }     
    system.debug('debug currID '+currID);
}
```

Comment: 2 level means you want to get the parent object's AccountId.. if so then you need to use soql to get the value

Comment: First of all why can't Salesforce see 2 levels up like I tried in the code? And secondly, how to setup the query to get the accountid?

Comment: Not populating the reference links (`__r` fields) is a Salesforce design decision; if they were automatically populated extra queries would have to be done by Salesforce all the time for triggers or whenever such a reference is found in a trigger. Instead you have to add the code when you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one level can be accessed in a trigger. You have to query the account using the Id of the contact record.

```
Id contactId;
for(BOG_Membership__c a: Trigger.new){
    contactId = a.Contact__c;
}
Id accountId = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Contact = :contactId].Id;
```

Comment: wow, is that documented somewhere?  I had no idea you couldn't query two levels higher

Comment: Where is accountMap defined? Also what is the syntax when one deletes a record?

Comment: Sorry. it was a mistake. I have made changes to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce does not allowed relationship record data retrieved at the time of trigger execution.but we can able to get the relationship field value from the `SOQL` execution.This code get `accountId` from `contact`. It may help your scenario.

```
Id currID;
Set<Id> conIds = new Set<Id>();
Map<Id,Id> conIdAndAccIdMap = new Map<Id,Id>();

for(BOG_Membership__c a : Trigger.new){
    if(a.Contact__c != null) {
        conIds.add(a.Contact__c);
    }

}  

if(conIds.size() > 0) {
    for(contact con : [SELECT Id,AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :conIds]) {
        conIdAndAccIdMap.put(con.Id,con.AccountId);
    }
}

for(BOG_Membership__c mem : Trigger.new){
    if(mem.Contact__c != null && conIdAndAccIdMap.containsKey(mem.Contact__c)) {
        currID = conIdAndAccIdMap.get(mem.Contact__c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A trigger will only provide information about the object that is being used within that trigger.  Imagine if Salesforce had to include information for all the parents, and all the parents' parents, etc.

To get your contact's parent, you'll need to query for it.  Because you're doing it in the trigger, you'll want to bulkify it as well.

```
trigger trgr_Update_BOG_Members_List on BOG_Membership__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    Map<ID, BOG_Membership__c> accountMap = [SELECT ID, Contact__r.AccountId FROM BOG_Membership__c WHERE ID IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()];

    for(BOG_Membership__c a: Trigger.new){
        currID = accountMap.get(a).Contact__r.AccountId;

        // do whatever you want with the ID
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give me the syntax for a deleted record? Is it exactly the same just change it to Trigger.Old?

Comment: My apologies. I marked your answer as answered as I was searching from bottom of page up but Juniad answered it first. Sorry.